# How can I click all the links in a web page with selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I really don't know the reason why it doesn't work for me. I must click on the links that are greater than 9 and less than 54, that is, only those on the left side of this page https://www.tabladecalories.net/
If I print the links, it shows them to me without any problem, but if I click on it, it sends me an error.

```
tag_a = driver.find_elements(by=By.TAG_NAME,value="a")

cont = 0;
for link in tag_a:
    if cont > 9 and cont < 54:
        driver.find_element(By.LINK_TEXT, link.text).click()
        time.sleep(4)        
    cont += 1
```

the error that I get is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\jluiso315\Desktop\informacionTablaDeAlimentos\main.py", line 34, in <module>
    driver.find_element(By.LINK_TEXT, link.text).click()
  File "C:\Users\jluiso315\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 77, in text
    return self._execute(Command.GET_ELEMENT_TEXT)['value']
  File "C:\Users\jluiso315\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 710, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "C:\Users\jluiso315\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 425, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\jluiso315\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 247, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
  (Session info: chrome=100.0.4896.75)
Stacktrace:
Backtrace:
    Ordinal0 [0x00659943+2595139]
    Ordinal0 [0x005EC9F1+2148849]
    Ordinal0 [0x004E4528+1066280]
    Ordinal0 [0x004E6E04+1076740]
```

Comment: Please include the error message in your post.

Answer (score 0):

What you should do is use a selenium recorder, like kathalon or selenium ide. You could get it in chrome web store.